# R - How to count number of columns in each row of a file before reading the file

Tags: r, io

I have a big file containing about 100K rows. Each row is supposed to have 17 columns, but since some of the columns are missing for some of the rows, those rows seem to have columns less than 17. I want to know those rows beforehand and not read them. How is this possible in R? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `count.fields()` function does exactly this. It takes most of the same parameters that `read.table()` would use. See the `?count.fields` help page for more info.

```
fc <- count.fields("myfile.txt")
which(fc != 17)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. This helps a lot!